# Wpf adding dynamic bitmap to an image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap

I'm having problems adding an image I just created but which is not stored at a location like"C:..."

So I was wondering if there was a way of adding that image to the wpf without it being needed to be first saved ....

Example of what I would of want.

```
Bitmap bit;
LoadBitmap(bit);
image = bit;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution in Tamir Khason's blog [here](http://khason.net/blog/how-to-use-systemdrawingbitmap-hbitmap-in-wpf/):

Using

```
public static BitmapSource ConvertBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
{ 
    return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                  source.GetHbitmap(),
                  IntPtr.Zero,
                  Int32Rect.Empty,
                  System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

you could do

```
Bitmap bit;
LoadBitmap(bit);
image.Source = ConvertBitmap(bit);
```

Comment: Awesome, I don't get the error now. Time to work and make the dynamic work :P... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BitmapImage.StreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) to create a BitmapImage directly from a Stream, without using GDI+ (`System.Drawing`).