# Anyway to make the interop faster

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, interop, performance

I got forced into using the interop to make bitmap images. Sadly enough it's slow... It reminds me of Windows Me.....

And I know I can store the images to a folder and reuse them later ... But I wouldn't want this speed ever ... Any ideas ?

here is my code.

```
private BitmapSource ConvertBitmap(Bitmap source)
    {
        return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
              source.GetHbitmap(),
              IntPtr.Zero,
              Int32Rect.Empty,
              System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
```

Comment: This is WPF, yes?  Tag your question appropriately.  It's almost certainly not the interop that's slow here, but the function you're calling.

Comment: yeah sorry thought i did... corrected

Answer (score 1):

> I got forced into using the interop to make bitmap images.

If you use the WPF classes directly, it will likely be faster.  What "forced" you to revert to `System.Drawing` to generate your images?

That being said, the main bottleneck is often a graphics subsystem issue.  In WPF, when image operations are slow, it can, and often is, due to graphics card limitations.  Try checking for newer graphics drivers, and potentially disabling hardware acceleration if you're on XP, as this can help quite a bit.

Comment: This is what forced me [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461306/wpf-adding-dynamic-bitmap-to-an-image)

Comment: @Reza: I just answered you there, as well, showing how to do it without GDI+.

Comment: I'll have to test out the graphic card. Just can't at the moment, so can't really say if it does resolve my problem. I was more looking for something in the line of an alternate route I can take.